# Eclipse RCP Key Listener Event issue in Linux

Tags: events, eclipse-rcp

In Eclipse RCP application, I am overriding a SWT key Listener in this way

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
    try {           
        if (e.stateMask == SWT.CTRL && e.keyCode ==99){
            //Some condition
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) { }
}
```

the  code

```
(e.stateMask == SWT.CTRL && e.keyCode ==99)
```

is  working well on Windows Platform, but on Ubuntu 12.04, the same is not working !!

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting an error? is the `keyPressed` method being called? If so, what keyCode are you seeing?

Comment: @david - I am not getting any Error. `keyPressed` method is being called and its working fine for Ctrl+F, but NOT for Ctrl+C !!